# Performance of SQL Query killed by join

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization, query-performance

We have a problem with performance of a query in SQL Server 2008 R2. The query joins tables from 2 databases, one which is our data mart getting data from the iSeries system, and one which is our main reporting System.

In the below query we should get 90939 records in less than 30 seconds. If we remove the column PO.POwner, the results come back in about 10 seconds.

But when we add the po.POwner column it is killing it.

```
  SELECT cu.* ,C4.C4IND, cu.CUS_Citizenship as [Country of Incorporation], 
  cu.CUS_Nationality as [Residence Country],[FirstParticipantID]=ISNULL(po.POwner,cu.CUS_No)
    -- , cu.CUS_No COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, po.POwner COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS  
  FROM dbo.CustomerData cu 
    left outer join Hermes_Import.dbo.KFILDTO_C4PF C4 
        on cu.CUS_Type COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS =C4.C4CTP COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 
            CASE WHEN GFCTP = 'GG' AND LEN(Y41SCV) > 5 THEN Y41SCV  ELSE Y41CUS END AS 'POwner', 
            GFCTP 
        FROM Hermes_Import.dbo.KFILDTO_Y41PF 
            INNER JOIN Hermes_Import.dbo.KFILDTO_GFPF ON GFCUS = Y41CUS 
        WHERE Y41TYP IN ('BN', 'BB', 'CO') AND Y41DEL = 0 AND Y41DEC = 0 
            AND Y41CUS COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = cu.CUS_No COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
        ) po 
    WHERE Left(Cu.[Cus_No],1)< '8' AND (cu.[CUS_Type])<>'ZA' AND DataDate='2014-04-30'  ORDER BY CUS_No
```

Here is the execution plan for that (just the TOP 3000 records):
[image]

When we take out the Primary Owner column , we get all the results in about 11 seconds and here is the execution plan:
[image]

What can we do differently to get the primary owner, bearing in mind that we want the first record of up to 6 possible participanst in a customers account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you don't get poor performance when you comment out the `po` fields is that `OUTER APPLY / TOP 1` is guaranteed to result exactly one record no matter what.

If you don't care about contents of this record, `SQL Server` could just as well optimize the whole clause out, which it does.

Create the following indexes:

```
Hermes_Import.dbo.KFILDTO_Y41PF (Y41CUS, Y41DEL, Y41DEC, Y41TYP)
Hermes_Import.dbo.KFILDTO_GFPF (GFCUS)
```

Also you are using TOP 1 without `ORDER BY` in your `OUTER APPLY`. Are you sure you don't care which record exactly are you selecting?

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking, but we cannot create indexes on those tables as that would have an impact on the overnight refresh process into Hermes_Import - we are mindful of the impact indexing the table may have on other functions that could be using the tables

Comment: also, yes you're right, we will add the `ORDER BY` in the `OUTER APPLY` clause after we have found our problem - we are leaning towards bringing a subset of the reference the tables into our reporting system as we only run this once per month to produce BASEL reporting files.

Comment: @Philip: how exactly are you afraid the tables will be impacted? Are they that large and written that heavily? Without an index you won't get decent performance on that query.

Comment: we're thinking of bringing accross the subset we need into the reporting database with the same collation as the reporting db, and on that table we wilkl use the indexes - we can do that task with a stored proc as part of the end of month data refresh to make it available for when we have to get the BASDEL report files prepared...

Comment: we're also testing on a temporary table which indexes give the best improvement in performance

Comment: we fixed the indexes and got it down to 9 minutes. Then I tried bringing over the reference data into a seperate table to store the data needed for the Primary Owner/Particpant, and well, it's now 5 seconds :) Thanks again!